# convert wstring_view to int

Tags: c++, string-view

I am trying to convert `wstring_view` to `int`. Is there something like `stoi` that works on `wstring_view` instead of `string`? Can't use any C-api's since it's not necessarily null-terminated. Can't use `from_chars` since it's `wchar_t`. So far, I've been converting to `std::wstring`, then converting to `int` (using `stoi`), which is probably OK with small string optimizations and all, but goes against the point of using views in the first place.

Comment: What about using stringstreams, does it work for you?

Comment: @anastaciu that's no better than converting to `wstring` first.

Comment: It's not, then I don't see how.

Comment: You still can manually iterate over the `wstring_view` and perform the conversion yourself. Using `std::stoi()` is a no-option since it will require to construct a `std::wstring` at some point anyway.

Comment: You could maybe build your own `string_view_stream` that reads characters from a view.  Or even use `std::num_get` directly with some sort of dummy `ios_base`-derived class to supply the format flags.  It's a lot of overhead though; copying the string may end up performing better and being simpler.

Comment: @Fareanor yes, it seems like I will end up writing a simple string to int conversion routine myself, but I was hoping std would have something useful.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Writing a whole stream is no good in my opinion. A simple conversion function should do. I was hoping std would have that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I found that works:

```
#include <cwchar>
#include <optional>
#include <string_view>

std::optional<int> StrToInt(std::wstring_view const view) noexcept {
  wchar_t format_str[13];  // % + 10digits + d + \0 = 13 characters
  std::swprintf(format_str, std::size(format_str), L"%%%dd", (int)view.size());

  int res;
  if (std::swscanf(view.data(), format_str, &res) != 1) return std::nullopt;
  return res;
}
```

Since we specify the size explicitly in `format_str`, view doesn't need to be null-terminated.

If we have verified that the string only contains numeric characters (no sign character, no leading or trailing spaces, etc.) and it won't overflow, we can use a simpler unchecked routine:

```
int UncheckedStrToInt(std::wstring_view const str) noexcept {
  int res = 0;
  for (auto ch : str)
    res = res * 10 + (ch - '0');
  return res;
}
```

I did some [benchmarks](https://quick-bench.com/q/X0L9CMAOuJnpi3EEe-rKACgL-nE). The `swscanf` performs much worse than `stoi`. I will be using `stoi` or `UncheckedStrToInt` depending on if the `wstring_view` is already verified.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoi(std::wstring)` is just a wrapper for [`std::wcstol()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcstol), which you can call directly.  However, it requires a null-terminated `wchar_t*` string, but `std::wstring_view` is not guaranteed to be null-terminated, as you noted.

Since a 32bit `int` has a maximum of 10 decimal digits, plus an optional sign, plus the null-terminator, you could simply copy the `std::wstring_view` data into a local `wchar_t[12]` array, null-terminate it, and then convert that with `std::wcstol()`, [`std::swscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwscanf), etc.

Alternatively, you can create a custom `FILE*` stream that reads from the `std::wstring_view` data, such as via [`fmemopen()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) or equivalent, and then you can use [`std::fwscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwscanf).

Alternatively, you can write a (or find a 3rd party) custom `std::basic_streambuf`-derived class that reads from the `std::wstring_view`, and then you can give an instance of that class to a standard `std::istream` object and use its `operator>>` to extract the `int`.

Comment: You may need to copy more than just 11 characters because `wcstol` also skips leading whitespace, and leading zeroes (or zeroes after the hex prefix) do not contribute significance but do occupy space.

Comment: @RaymondChen It would be trivial to take a pointer to the `wstring_view` data and advance it past any leading whitespace and leading zeros before then copying the remaining data into a buffer.

Comment: I feel like creating a wstring and trusting small string optimization is a better option than these.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili sure, if 1) SSO is implemented at all, and 2) the SSO buffer is large enough. The OP didn't dismiss that possibility: "*which is **probably OK with small string optimizations** and all, but goes against the point of using views in the first place.*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau Slightly less trivial to skip the insignificant leading 0's in `0x000000000000000000ff`. And don't skip the first leading 0 in `00xa` because that changes a 0 to a 10. Getting the various edge cases leads you about 80% of the way to just implementing the whole function yourself.

Comment: It seems possible to use `swscanf` by specifying the size explicitly even without a null-terminator. But since `scanf` family doesn't support `*` syntax, we additionally have to use `swprintf` to prepare the format string. It ends up perfoming worse than `stoi` in my testing. I added an answer summarizing that.